# Regex to match a line if it has the word and the same word should not be selected

Tags: regex

I want a regex which needs to find a match if the next word is specifically given

```
SAMPLE TEST ONE 
SAMPLE DIFF ONE
```

My regex should select the line which don't have `TEST` next to `SAMPLE`

It should select the line

```
SAMPLE DIFF ONE
```

Comment: Please define "next to" and show what you've tried so far, let's not duplicate your efforts

Comment: I just tried the negative look ahead but it didnt work

^SAMPLE\s*(?!TEST)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
^(?!.*?\bSAMPLE\s*TEST\b).*$
```

You can add a simple `lookahead` for that.See demo.

https://regex101.com/r/hE4jH0/35

Your regex will work too ,if you make `space` mandatory.The reason is if you dont have space mandatory after `SAMPLE` regex will check for `TEST` but there is a `space` So it will pass all.

```
^SAMPLE\s++(?!TEST).*$
```

See demo.

https://regex101.com/r/hE4jH0/39

Comment: For the `\s+` to be meaningful you would need to make it `\s++`. Do you see why?

Comment: in this below link its fetching the 3rd line which has two space between SPACE and TEST

https://regex101.com/r/hE4jH0/38

Comment: @KarthikSV https://regex101.com/r/hE4jH0/39 or you can use this or https://regex101.com/r/hE4jH0/40

Comment: @pguardiario got you point.Have modified to include `++` thanx a lot